# How to store a type as member?

Tags: pointers, c++11, types

I am building a simple scheduler, which takes functions as parameter, puts them in a queue and executes them at a later time. The class is intended to be [inherited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), and later `enqueue(function_ptr)` to be called from the methods of the child class.

My problem is that the scheduling will be happening based on time, and that is measured with a 2ms interrupt. One can subscribe for callbacks from the interrupt handler, but those return only a `void*` to the object that got subscribed.

*So how can I know what is the type of the object being passed back, so that I can cast it and call the appropriate method?*

I was thinking about template parameter at `class Scheduler` creation, but then the callback function doesn't know what the template parameter was. So maybe some way of storing `Scheduler`'s child class inside a member variable - cast `object` to `Scheduler` and looking at that field, cast it to the final type? I guess this can be solved by a global `enum` of schedulable classes, but that seems like a bad solution.

Or maybe my whole approach of this is wrong?

---

Here is some code for the Scheduler. I was refraining from posting, because possibly my whole approach is wrong.

```
class Scheduler {
     private: std::vector<QueueItem> m_queue;
     protected: void schedule(void *foo_ptr);
     public: void callback_2ms_passed();  // Note that we are getting only 'this' as a parameter.
}
class Child1 : public Scheduler, public OtherClasses {
    void slow_foo(bool execute_immediately = false) {
        if(!execute_immediately)
            schedule(slow_foo);
        else
            // Do slow stuff.
    }
}
```

The idea is that the scheduler decides when at a later moment to call the slow function, and does it with parameter `true` so that the actual calculations are made.

Comment: How do you define "appropriate method"? How does it differ from inappropriate ones? Why does `Scheduler` need to know what class is being derived from it? Can you show some code demonstrating what `Scheduler` looks like, and how it's intended to be used?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I was trying to outline my goal more than the implementation. I have added my approach above, but it is entirely possible that another architecture, e.g. composition, would suit the task better.

Comment: Technically, you could use `std::function<void()>`, which is a perfect abstraction for an action. Insert items with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Your lambdas could i.e. contain side-effects, as assigning a value somewhere, or calling methods of other objects

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov, this approach sounds great. However, it turns out I am using [quite an old compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907586/stdfunction-has-no-member-named-target).

Comment: @Vorac: why not switch to a newer compiler? In any case, you could probably substitute it with Boost [function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/function.html) & [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bind/bind.html)

Comment: If `Scheduler` were a template, used as in `class Child1 : public Scheduler<Child1>`, then `callback_2ms_passed` would have access to `Child1` via a template parameter. What makes you believe otherwise?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov, thank you a lot. I used `std::function` and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for are delegates. Since you don't want to use boost or the other mentioned implementations of delegates you could try this.

```
SomeObject obj;
delegate d = delegate::from_member<SomeObject, 
              &SomeObject::someMethod>(&obj);
```

Your Scheduler should use delegate objects in your vector.
Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates